# Recover deleted branch in GitHub desktop

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I'm new to GitHub and have been using GitHub Desktop to collaborate on a group project at uni.
I had cloned a remote repo onto my computer and was working on a branch on it, and had locally committed it several times. 
I then accidentally deleted the branch without realising that this would delete all of the files on my computer.
I would really like to be able to recover the lost files as I'd been working on them for a few weeks!

I have seen several posts about using 
    git reflog, 
but I'm really new to git and have no idea how to access the repo I was working on GitHub Desktop with through git.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Are you running Windows or Mac?

Answer (score -1):

Solved the problem!! before using **git reflog** you need to **cd** into the correct directory first.